# Filter with range of order reference in list view of sale ordres?

Tags: python, xml, filter, odoo

i have a list Sales orders from S001 to S120 and i want to filter this list from S010 to S050.
can i search with range Order Reference, i want a list depends on Order Reference range not date because i didn't found operator between in Order reference.

please any help, thanks

Comment: There is no between operator for char fields in Odoo. So you either have to implement it yourself or try to find someting in the community.

Comment: PLease add the code you are working on so we can have a loo.

Comment: Please add the code for the related query and info about environemnt